# VB.Net web app Delay in breakpoint hit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on a `VB.Net web application`. If I placed a break-point in `Page_Init` event of the page. After hitting reload in browser, it takes around 5-6 seconds to hit that break-point. Whereas in my other application it hits almost instantly.

Any help on this would be a great help for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem. My application uses microsoft assess db. Those db files(.mdb file) are placed inside the bin folder as some of the db file is required by a third party dll to be place in the same location as the dll. Now I placed a copy of the .mbd file in the `App_Data` and changed the connection string accordingly. Now I got tremendous speed improvement.

This behavior was really strange. It's not taking time to complete the db call and get the result. It was taking time to hit the server method.

Anyway this solution makes my day. I post it here just in case someone else face the same and this might help.